# How to export FTP-data from several packages

Tags: ftp, export, wireshark, pcap

I've been trying for hours to solve this. Googling like a maniac aswell. How do I export the FTP-data from a bunch of packages? Like when you export HTTP-packages in Wireshark, in just a few clicks you can export all packages as a single one to a file and then just open the HTML page.

Lets say you downloaded a .zip file (through FTP) and you caught this with Wireshark. Now I want to export all those FTP-data packages containing the .zip file to a copy of the .zip file. How can I do that? I managed to get all hexdumps (I think that's what it is called) of the packages, and it looks like this:

```
0000  00 50 56 ca 11 d8 00 50 18 03 39 80 08 00 45 00   .PV....P..9...E.
0010  04 34 06 34 40 00 2d 06 d3 6f c1 e7 ec 2a c0 a8   .4.4@.-..o...*..
etc...
```

Maybe I can convert that somehow? Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bro](http://www.bro-ids.org) to extract files from FTP traffic (and other protocols as well). Simply run it as follows:

```
bro -r trace.pcap 'FTP::extract_file_types = /.*/'
```

The pattern controls the MIME type of the files to extract. Change `-r <trace>` to `-i <interface>` when sniffing on a network interface. Bro creates log files in the same directory it is being run. In addition to the basic logs, you'll now find files named

```
ftp-item_<SERVER-IP>:<SERVER-DATA-PORT>-<CLIENT-IP>:<CLIENT-PORT>.dat
```

which contain the payload of the FTP data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems promising! I get this error though: `<params>, line 1 (FTP::extract_file_types): error, "redef" used but not previously defined`

Comment: Would you mind trying the current [git master](http://git.bro-ids.org/bro.git/shortlog/refs/heads/master) (`git clone --recursive git://git.bro-ids.org/bro.git`)? I tested this invocation locally and it works for me. There were some changes to the file extraction framework after the 2.0 release.